# SharePoint form - generate output based on selections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, form

I'm fairly new to SharePoint 2013, but have learned not to underestimate what it can do. I have a vision for what I want to accomplish, but am not quite sure if it would even be possible. And before I waste unnecessary time, I'm hoping one of you Guru's could help.

I am hoping to use SP to generate an output of hyperlinks based on user submitted data.

I currently have a generic link to a survey form (outside of SharePoint via another tool). What I would like to do is append additional data to the generic link,  based on user selection, so that this additional data can be captured in the survey. (which I can do in the survey application, as long as I append this info)

My generic link would look something like this: 
www.mysurvey.com/newproject

I would like users to submit the following (variable) data:
Name, email, project type (and also select which survey forms they would like to produce links for - new project, old project, etc.)

I would then like, once the form is submitted and based on this data, for an output to be generated containing the links amended with the above info (maybe even with a message like: here is the info you requested)

This is what my amended link should look like:
www.mysurvey.com/newproject?Name=John&Email=john@john.com&projecttype=blue

Any ideas?

Thank you all so very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got two solutions for your problem,
1. Just create a Calculated Column, to bind the parameters together as a string.
2. If it has to be a hyperlink column, then create a list workflow with SharePoint Designer to update this link every time when a new item is created or existing item was edited.